# I have an error in auto increment column.during after error record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

in sql server 2008

```sql
create table Person ( Person_ID bigint identity (1,1) not null Constraint PersonID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID)
```

it should increment `id` by 1 number when record is correct like 12345. an error occur during fill the other column record on person table but on next time it should not increment by 1 it miss. 123 error occur next `id` value is 5, two error next `id` value is 8,9,10,11 two error next `id` value is 13 plz tell me the solution how i auto increment that during error it should not miss the value.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, when you have an Identity column in the table, and when you insert a record to this table, if the insert failed for example, because of checking constraint, the idenitity will still increase.

If you want to prevent that to happen. You can try to create a "instead of " trigger. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
 ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
) 
INSERT INTO TestTableVALUES ('Bob')
-- This will fail since NULL is not allowed
-- But id still +1
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Mike')
-- Create INSTEAD OF trigger
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger
ON TestTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
-- Get the value(s) being inserted 
-- and repeat the insert
Declare @value varchar(100)
SET @value = (SELECT Name FROM Inserted)
-- If this statement fails, SQL won't increase the IDENTITY
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (@value)
-- Run the same INSERT again, when failed, ID will not increase
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('test1')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('test2')
SELECT * FROM TestTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way, just for your second opnion

After each time your insert failed, you can reset the seed

```
declare @maxid int
SELECT @maxid = MAX(id) FROM TestTable
DBCC CHECKIDENT('testtable',RESEED, @maxid ) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

user following code to test, it works.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('test1')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(NULL)
...reset seed
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('test2')
select * from TestTable
```